# Android O: DragShadowBuilder throws IllegalStateException: Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap

My Android app allows users to drag and drop images in an activity. It used to work fine until Android O and hardware image acceleration arrived. The code throws the following exception now:

> IllegalStateException: Software rendering doesn't support hardware
>   bitmaps

Here is my code:

```
public class PhotoDragShadowBuilder extends DragShadowBuilder {
    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        Drawable photoDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        photoDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

The Bitmap inside of `imageView.getDrawable()` has the flag `Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE` set. It means that the bitmap is only stored in hardware. Android refuses to draw the Bitmap to the canvas that's stored in heap.

The responsible Android source code for the exception is here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/BaseCanvas.java#532

Obviously, I could load the Bitmap a second time for dragging and dropping. However, that's extra work for the device plus requires tying together a lot of nicely decoupled code.

Is there a way to fix this? Is there a way to get the Bitmap out of the hardware and into heap?

Answer (score 0):

This Glide issue on the Glide web site explains what's going on:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2309

The solution is to disable hardware acceleration in Glide:
http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/431/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestOptions.html#disallowHardwareConfig--

> Disables the use of Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE in Downsampler to avoid errors caused by [...] drawing to Canvass backed by Bitmaps

The code below shows how to disable hardware acceleration for the specific image.

```
            GlideApp.with(context)
                .applyDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions().disallowHardwareConfig())
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for ANDROID O causes an error"IllegalStateException: Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps".

Recode your public class GlideConfiguration extends AppGlideModule as below:

```
    RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
    boolean isAndroidO = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O);
    DecodeFormat format = isAndroidO ? DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888 : DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565;
    options.format(format);
    if (isAndroidO) options.disallowHardwareConfig();

    builder.setDiskCache(new InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory(context, diskCacheSizeBytes));
    builder.setDefaultRequestOptions(options);
```

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer:- I didn't use glide in this activity still I was getting `"IllegalStateException: Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps"`

I solved this error by creating a new activity and copy the code block while also checking does my app run after adding code.

finally, my app is running without any error and I didn't get why this error was thrown.