# canvas.drawBitmap fatal error api 29 android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to run my app in api 29 and have this error on it:

> Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps

I find another questions but the answer was in kotlin and I couldn't apply them in my case.

My code:

```
Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
Rect rectangle = new Rect(0,0,500,500);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray.get(i), null, rectangle, null);
```

How can I make it work in api 29?

Comment: Could you please mention that kotlin answer? It should be translatable to java.

Comment: create Bitmap without HARDWARE config

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723107/canvas-drawbitmap-software-rendering-doesnt-support-hardware-bitmaps?rq=1

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765750/android-o-dragshadowbuilder-throws-illegalstateexception-software-rendering-do?rq=1

Comment: @Style-7 I try to convert: `Bitmap convertedBitmap = convert(bitmapArray.get(i), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);` but the error is the same.

Comment: Use Bitmap.copy with mutable flag